# Submit Button that activates a PHP function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, onclick

Okay,  I'm creating a challenge system on a website. I will list out in each step what happens to get to where the submit button will be in hopes this helps make it easier to understand..

There is a challenge button listed beside each user of the website page.

When you click the challenge button a MODAL window pops up displaying each of that users characters. Each character listed in the modal window has its own challenge button underneath the character details and to the left of each character is a drop-down menu that lists your characters. (The current logged in user that is viewing the page)

Now what I want is the logged in user has to select one of their characters from the dropdown before the challenge button activates the server side code/function/whatever it needs to be.

Once the logged in user has selected one of their characters from the drop down menu. They can click the challenge button and it will activate a function that I have already made that will create a custom_post_type and then upload a generic featured image which the featured image will be displayed on the homepage slider.

After that, another POP-UP happens on screen saying Challenge Successful or Not. Keep in mind this is already in a MODAL window so it would be a popup over a popup so to speak.

I know virtually zip about javascript and I'm hoping this can be done strictly with PHP. I've read that using isset makes it possible but I've not figured out how to successfully do it yet.

Something like....

```
if(isset($_POST['challenge']))
{

  all of the code that happens after successful click goes here.

}
```

My current code for the button is this...

```
<div class="challenge_button">                           
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">                                         
        <input type="button" name="challenge" value="Challenge">        
    </form>                                                   
</div>
```

Example code for the drop down:

Choose Your Champion

```
<select name="contender">                                                            
   <option value="0"> ----- </option>                                                        
   <option value="1">1</option>                                                            
   <option value="2">2</option>         
   <option value="3">3</option>                                                      
   <option value="4">4</option>                                         
   <option value="5">5</option>                                             
   <option value="6">6</option>                                             
   <option value="7">7</option>                                             
   <option value="8">8</option>                                         
</select>
```

Now how would I tie all of this together if at all possible?

Something like..............

```
<div class="challenge_button">  
    <?php                        
        if (((((drop-down is set return true & grab which option was set and save as variable)))))
        {
            <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">                                         
                <input type="button" name="challenge" value="Challenge">        
            </form>
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'You must setup a champion before you can challenge someone.';
            echo 'div class="setup">';
            echo 'You can setup your champion <a href="#">here<a>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

then................

if the code runs successfully a popup over the modal window. I dont want the page to refresh or go to another page. Just a popup saying Challenge Successful or unsuccessful if certain variables aren't met.

Went with an alternative solution that isn't as cool. Even in this method the colorbox don't work blah.

The javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function loadPage(list) 
    {
        location.href=list.options[list.selectedIndex].value  
    }
</script>
```

The Variables:

```
                                            $cuser  =   wp_get_current_user();
                                            $v1     =   get_cimyFieldValue($cuser->ID, 'character_name');
                                            $v2     =   get_cimyFieldValue($cuser->ID, 'character_name2');
                                            $v3     =   get_cimyFieldValue($cuser->ID, 'character_name3');
                                            $v4     =   get_cimyFieldValue($cuser->ID, 'character_name4');
                                            $v5     =   get_cimyFieldValue($cuser->ID, 'character_name5');
                                            $v6     =   get_cimyFieldValue($cuser->ID, 'character_name6');
                                            $v7     =   get_cimyFieldValue($cuser->ID, 'character_name7');
                                            $v8     =   get_cimyFieldValue($cuser->ID, 'character_name8');
                                            $add    =   'http://conspirators.websitedesignbyneo.com/wp-content/themes/conspirators/single-challenge.php?';
                                            $metak  =   'class="zoom cboxelement"';
$challenged =   $v['toon_name'];
```

The Form:

```
                                                    <form>
                                                        Choose Your Champion:
                                                        <select name="contender"
                                                            size="1"
                                                            onchange="loadPage(this.form.elements[0])"
                                                            target="_parent._top"
                                                            onmouseclick="this.focus()">
                                                                <option value="0"></option>
                                                                <?php if ($v1){echo '<option value="'.$add.'challenged='.$challenged.'&challenger='.$v1.'"'.$metak.'>'.$v1.'</option>';}?>
                                                                <?php if ($v2){echo '<option value="'.$add.'challenged='.$challenged.'&challenger='.$v2.'"'.$metak.'>'.$v2.'</option>';}?>
                                                                <?php if ($v3){echo '<option value="'.$add.'challenged='.$challenged.'&challenger='.$v3.'"'.$metak.'>'.$v3.'</option>';}?>
                                                                <?php if ($v4){echo '<option value="'.$add.'challenged='.$challenged.'&challenger='.$v4.'"'.$metak.'>'.$v4.'</option>';}?>
                                                                <?php if ($v5){echo '<option value="'.$add.'challenged='.$challenged.'&challenger='.$v5.'"'.$metak.'>'.$v5.'</option>';}?>
                                                                <?php if ($v6){echo '<option value="'.$add.'challenged='.$challenged.'&challenger='.$v6.'"'.$metak.'>'.$v6.'</option>';}?>
                                                                <?php if ($v7){echo '<option value="'.$add.'challenged='.$challenged.'&challenger='.$v7.'"'.$metak.'>'.$v7.'</option>';}?>
                                                                <?php if ($v8){echo '<option value="'.$add.'challenged='.$challenged.'&challenger='.$v8.'"'.$metak.'>'.$v8.'</option>';}?>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </form>
```

Comment: you can't do that. you'll need AJAX for that

Comment: As Chasing Death says you can't do this without a page refresh just using php, you would have to implement some javascript / jQuery to achieve that.

Comment: By pressing the button, you can make sth. happen on client-side. PHP runs on serverside, so after you requested a page and you get an answer, you haven't access to php anymore, unless you use ajax. You can do it the native way: http://ajax.frozenfox.at/ or with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is an error in your code, which is the following: `<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">` will always return `<form action="" method="post">`, as `$_SERVER` is an array which have to be echoed: use this `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`

Then, as code for your php this works well: it receives two vars from POST, and if the `contender` (which is the select) contains a value different from 0, it will put it inside the `$contender` variable. At this point, you can use this variable in your function.

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['challenge'])): ?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
Choose Your Champion:

<select name="contender">                                                            
   <option value="0"> ----- </option>                                                        
   <option value="1">1</option>                                                            
   <option value="2">2</option>         
   <option value="3">3</option>                                                      
   <option value="4">4</option>                                         
   <option value="5">5</option>                                             
   <option value="6">6</option>                                             
   <option value="7">7</option>                                             
   <option value="8">8</option>                                         
</select>
<div class="challenge_button">                           
        <input type="submit" name="challenge" value="Challenge">                                                  
</div>
    </form>
<div id="result">
</div><?php endif; ?>
<?php

if ($_POST['contender']!=="0" &&        // So, the select has to be selected
    isset($_POST['challenge'])) {       // And so does the button (however you can drop this condition)
    // |    This variable contains the user's choice (from 1 to 8)
    // v
    $contender = $_POST['contender'];
    // Here goes your code or function...
}
```

Now, if you want this to return an OK or an error *whithout reloading the page*, you **have to** use AJAX. For example, you could use a JS function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(btn, contender) {
var ajax;

// Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    ajax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
}
}
ajax.open("GET","<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?challenge=" + btn + "&contender=" + contender, true);
ajax.send();

}
</script>
```

Together with this button:

```
<input type="button" id="challenge" name="challenge" value="Challenge" onclick="loadXMLDoc(document.getElementById('challenge').value, document.getElementById('contender').options[document.getElementById('contender').selectedIndex].value)">
```

What it does is getting the current values of the select and of the input (this is rather for thoroughness, you could remove it), and passing them to the `loadXMLDoc()` function, which will transfer them directly to the PHP using GET method (there's no reason to use POST). The PHP will do whatever you want with the select value, and eventually return an OK or an error. For instance:

```
<?php    
if ($_GET['contender']!=="0" && isset($_GET['challenge'])) {
    $contender = $_GET['contender'];
    // Here goes your code...
    echo "All done.";
} else
    echo "Something went wrong.";
```

You could possibly direct that output to your lightbox/popup to create your second modal window.

Also, I would suggest making all that AJAX stuff with jQuery, it makes it way easier.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the indepth answer Marco. I tried getting this to work, and the colorbox just loads and goes nowhere. Would you mind doing a quick look through of the code to see what I'm missing? I eliminated several hundred lines of code which is just repeats for each character reference which will go up to a max of 8 for each user. Here's the link: http://codepad.org/937Mgcl7

Comment: Oh also pay no mind to the function create_challenge() is a place holder i haven't put it in yet.

Also this is what is inside of single-challenge.php

     `<?php    
        if ($_GET['contender']!=="0" && isset($_GET['challenge'])) 
        {
            $contender = $_GET['contender'];
            // Here goes your code...
            echo "All done.";
        } 
        else
        {
        echo "Something went wrong.";
        }
    ?>`

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy my work was useful. In your code, as much as I see you mixed my two different PHP codes, which weren't meant to run toghether: you correctly put my last code in `single-challenge.php`, but you also copied a useless part of the first in the Roster Page. To clear things up: this is what goes into the main page http://pastebin.com/Db7ABLj1 . **To edit the target file location** (single-challenge.php) DO NOT edit the `<input>` but the `$single_challenge_loc` variable I've created.
In the past version I was assuming that script was the file itself (that's why $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])

Comment: Hey Marco, thanks for your patience and help, I unfortunately just could not get this to work and I cannot invest anymore time in it. what I ended up doing is listed above.

Comment: Well yes, it should work anyway, but:
1. You will have to reload the page
2. Users who accidentally choose the wrong champion won't be given the option to correct their choice, as the form will be immediately submitted.
3. You have no reason to use JS to "submit" the form: simply specify the target through `action =""` and use a submit button to send it.
Still, I see no reason why my code shouldn't work (of course I've tested it on my pc). Maybe if you could paste again your current code and tell me exactly what happens I could help you further.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted it to be only PHP without Javascript, you would have to sacrifice the 'must not refresh' constraint, as the only way to submit the form is by pressing the button, and submitting the content.

However, with a little bit of Javascript, you could make the challenge button work using something AJAX like. The workflow might be something like this:

Page Loads,
MODAL(?) popup opens, 
User clicks 'Challenge', 
Form is submitted to server (using XMLHTTPRequest or other AJAX-like mechaninsm),

Meanwhile:
Page periodically checks server for challenge request (AJAX again), and displays messages accordingly.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
<script>
$("#challenge").click(function(){
$.post("page",{"name":"value"},function(response){})
});
</script>
<div class="challenge_button">                                                       
        <input type="button" id="challenge" name="challenge" value="Challenge">                                                         
</div>
```

Comment: If he sticks that code in his page it will do nothing except complain about $ not being defined.

Comment: its not code its example and yes he may get that error if he don't include jquery in page

Comment: Sorry that came out nothing like I meant it to, he mentions he knows almost nothing about javascript, it might be wise to update your example to help him a little more.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use PHP like that, If you want to do something like that you must use PHP Ajax. Here you go for the link that helps you to understand about Ajax.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp